# Displaying more than 20 photos in instagram API

Tags: javascript, jquery, instagram

I've been doing some research and trying to figure out how to display more then 20 images that are being pulld in from the instagram api. I'm pretty new at this so any help would be appreciated! Just trying to see if there are any work arounds? Saw something about adding pagination that could possibly help.. if thats the case details on how to do that would be great too!

Here's the code I have so far.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        cache: false,
        url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/coffee/media/recent?client_id=[]&access_token=[]",
        success: function(data)  {
            for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                $(".instagram").append("<a class='big-square span2' target='_blank' href='" + data.data[i].link +"'><img src='" + data.data[i].images.low_resolution.url +"'></img></a>");
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please note also that there is a recently (Nov 2015) introduced limit of 20 images for applications in sandbox mode. 
It took me forever to find that out because the top answers shown in Google don't mention this. So i am adding that now.

Answer (score 11):

Instagram has a 20 image limit on their API, check out this thread and my answer:

[What is the maximum number of requests for Instagram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322028/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-requests-for-instagram)

**EDIT: also, have a look at [THIS](http://thegregthompson.com/old_site/displaying-instagram-images-ignoring-page-pagination/)**

Answer (score 5):

Any app created before Nov 17, 2015 will continue to function until June 2016. After June 2016, the app will automatically be moved to Sandbox Mode if it wasn't approved through the review process.
Sandbox mode are real Instagram data (i.e. what is normally visible in the Instagram app), but with the following conditions:

- Apps in sandbox are restricted to 10 users
- **Data is restricted to the 10 users and the 20 most recent media from each of those users**
- Reduced API rate limits

[more info](https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/)

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding `&count=N` to the request, where N is the number of results you want.

Comment: I tried that and it still only limits me to 20.. Now i'm entertaining the idea of having pagination, which I think its the initial thought behind it for instagram.

Comment: &count=33 this a maximum

Answer (score 3):

Try this code

```
$api = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/snow/media/recent?client_id=".$client;  

function get_curl($url) {  
    if(function_exists('curl_init')) {  
        $ch = curl_init();  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);   
        $output = curl_exec($ch);  
        echo curl_error($ch);  
        curl_close($ch);  
        return $output;  
    } else{  
        return file_get_contents($url);  
    }  
}

while ($api !== NULL) {
    $response = get_curl($api);
    foreach(json_decode($response)->data as $item){   
        $src = $item->images->standard_resolution->url;  
        $thumb = $item->images->thumbnail->url;  
        $url = $item->link;  

        $images[] = array(  
        "src" => htmlspecialchars($src),  
        "thumb" => htmlspecialchars($thumb),  
        "url" => htmlspecialchars($url)  
        );  
    echo "<a href='".$src."'><img src='".$thumb."'  width='150' height='150' border='0'></a> ";
    } 
    $api = json_decode($response)->pagination->next_url;
}
```

Comment: could you tell me what is $images[] array is used for ? Furthermore, how i can insert all response to mysql db? where should i put the insert statement ?

Comment: the $images[] array stores all the fetched instagram images with attributes of image src, image thumb, and image url, you could use that array to insert the image item into mysql

Comment: Many thanks for your explanation ! Could you explain to me how i should save api response so i get order of pictures same way as instagram app(latest image on top) when displaying data from mysql? What sort order should i use so i get latest pic on the top? Is there any reverse saving option in mysql?

Comment: Replace the `while ($api !== NULL)` with `if ($api !== NULL)`. Otherwise this will cause a request that will keep going and going until timeout.

Answer (score 1):

See http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/. It details the generics of the endpoints, also listing the pagination attributes. In short, a 'paginated' response will include a `next_url` that can be used to retrieve the next set of results. Subsequentially retrieving all next URLs (as long as they are supplied in the result) will get you the complete set.

BTW, you can try to increase the `count` parameter in the request. (Depending on the Instagram library you are using, such things can be supplied via an `options` hash or something similar.) That might save you a couple of extra requests. The page I just mentioned doesn't specify a maximum count value though. I suspect that Instagram is changing the maximum dynamically, and per endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

You can get more than 20 items by specifying a `count` parameter and set it to the number you want.

However, Instagram also imposes an undocumented limit of 33 for every request you make, and so you'd have to paginate if you get more than 33.

However, I have written [**Instafetch**](https://github.com/d4nyll/instafetch) which will help you paginate, it will even filter media by tags for you. So feel free to use it!

Answer (score 1):

You can't get more than 20 posts, if you are a sandbox user
please read under "API BEHAVIOUR" [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/)

Comment: This answer, including your link, has been given before in this thread multiple times and all of them are more substantial than this one. To make SO more helpful for users looking for help, answers should not be repeated ...

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

### Old question. New answer.

Here's the solution for 2021.

You will need to use the [Instagram Basic Display API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/overview) to display media items. (This answer doesn't cover setting that up).

Assuming correct setup of the above, **you can use the *limit* parameter to control how many media results the API returns**.

The **default is 25** (with no limit set) and the **maximum allowed is 100**. (You might potentially get more results using pagination but again that is off topic).

The below cURL code example is using the [Me endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/me).

```
GET https://graph.instagram.com/me
    ?fields={fields}
    &access_token={access-token}
    &limit={required number of items}
```

Comment: This is the current correct answer in 2022. There is also a 10k total max limit when using their pagination. Documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/user/media/)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a chance to get the next 20 pictures, and after that the next 20 and so on...
In the JSON responce there is an "**pagination**" array:

```
 "pagination":{
      "next_max_tag_id":"1411892342253728",
      "deprecation_warning":"next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead",
      "next_max_id":"1411892342253728",
      "next_min_id":"1414849145899763",
      "min_tag_id":"1414849145899763",
      "next_url":"https:\/\/api.instagram.com\/v1\/tags\/lemonbarclub\/media\/recent?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\u0026max_tag_id=1411892342253728"
 }
```

this is the information on specific API call and the object "**next_url**" shows the URL to get the next 20 pictures so just take that URL and call it for the next 20 pictures...

for more information about Instagram API check this out: https://medium.com/@KevinMcAlear/getting-friendly-with-instagrams-api-abe3b929bc52

Comment: In response for https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN there no pagination field or next_url field in response.
any idea that what happened?

Comment: got it, in sandbox mode, it will restrict to 20 media, not a single more

Answer (score 0):

You can use Instagram feeds libraries like [instafeed](http://instafeedjs.com/). It allows to get feed of 60 images (maximum)

Eg:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var feed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'tagged',
        tagName: 'awesome',
        limit: 20,
        clientId: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
    });
    feed.run();
</script>
```

limit (number) - Maximum number of Images to add. Max of 60.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var token = 'your_token',
    userid = your_id,
    num_photos = 12;
    $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/'+userid+'/media/recent',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {access_token: token, count: num_photos},
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(data){
            }
        });
</script>
```

[12 photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5fsx.png)

https://rudrastyh.com/javascript/get-photos-from-instagram.html

Comment: Please add some context around the code.  Also, the code doesn't execute.\

Comment: You need token and user id.