# What is the maximum number of requests for Instagram?

Tags: json, api, jquery, jsonp, instagram

I was wondering if there is a limitation of the number of images that are tagged that you can return?

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    dataType:'jsonp',
    cache: false,
    url:'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/[TAG NAME]/media/recent?client_id=[CLIENT ID]',
    success: function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        $(".pics").append("<li><a target='_blank' href='" + data.data[i].link +
        "' class='upshot-instagram' rel='instagram-group'><img src='" + data.data[i].images.thumbnail.url +"' ></img></a></li>");
        }
    }
});
});
</script>
```

I have 50 returning but I am only getting 20 images coming back to me. I know we have over 250 that have been tagged.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The API will only return 20 images per call. This is where the `pagination` data will come in handy, you can use the `MAX_ID` provided by the Instagram API, read more [here](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/).

This is in PHP and jQuery, but it can help you get on the right track: [load more example](https://gist.github.com/2961185)

Comment: found out from experience... try making a call using their API

Comment: I have. It defaults to 20 items, but you can request more with the count parameter. 40 appears to be the limit, but this doesn't appear to be set in stone.

Comment: Yeah, so nevermind. I was looking at a different API method in the docs. I'm leaving my previous comments, because I think it's still important to note that 20 is the default, not a specified maximum (i.e. it could change at any time).

Comment: Also, note that the `popular` endpoint will only return 16. Just a heads up--it bit me :)

Comment: Link to Instagram API page is broken.

Answer (score 1):

The default number of items returned is 20. However, you can specify more using a `count` parameter. At the time of this writing, it appears to be 33, but that could change as it is undocumented.

So the answer to your question is - 33, but it can (and probably will) change.

To answer your *problem*, you can use [**Instafetch**](https://github.com/d4nyll/instafetch), a script I wrote, which will paginate and filter for you, and allows you to fetch as many pictures as you specify.

Answer (score 0):

In 2021, using the [Instagram Basic Display API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/overview), the default number of media returned is 25. If the limit parameter is used, you exceed this default, but **the maximum number of items returned is 100**.

Here is an example cURL code snippet using the [Me endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/me):

```
GET https://graph.instagram.com/me
    ?fields={fields}
    &access_token={access-token}
    &limit={required number of items}
```