# How to get more then 20 images using locaton api in Instagram

Tags: php, instagram

i am writing Php code to get Instagram images on behalf of location api . But all time i am getting only 20 images . Can any body help me to shortout this issue .please see code .

```
    $client = new Zend_Http_Client('https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search');
    $client->setParameterGet('client_id', $CLIENT_ID);
    $client->setParameterGet('lat', $_POST['lat']);
    $client->setParameterGet('lng', $_POST['long']);
   $client->setParameterGet('distance', $_POST['distance']);
```

Comment: Maybe you have only 20 images in the vicinity? That said, what's the value of distance?

Comment: We have given value of distance 5km to 50km but result was same. i have use diffrent location but images was same . Is there any other way to fetch more images using loction api ?

Comment: The distance is in meters. So if you want 5km you need to set distance to `5000`. Also 5km is the max according to their [API](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/).

Comment: Yes i have given the same .... 5000 but result is same. and i know 5000 is max

Comment: Do you have a `pagination` index in the response? If so, try to launch another query against the value of `next_url`.

Comment: Heya. Until now I've just been quoting from [the docs](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/), specifically [the media section](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/). If that's all what you're getting then the only logical problem I can see is that there are only 20 images associated with those settings. So try to use other coordinates. If it doesn't work then maybe there's some "undocumented" limit. If that's the case I think you should report it to the developers of instagram with a clear [POC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_concept).

Comment: So it really seems there's a 20 image limit. [See this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12374850). Like I said earlier, you should have some `pagination` in the response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66644/discussion-between-conrad-media-and-hamza).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By passing the *undocumented* `count` parameter you can get more results.

This API endpoint does not provide pagination but using the `count` parameter you can receive up to 100 medias.

Comment: There is no count parameter in Location api .

Comment: As I said it is "undocumented", just set a `count` and it works as far as I tested: 

https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=47.858844&lng=2.494351&distance=1000000&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&count=50000

it returns up to 100 results or the specified COUNT if less than 100.