# How to change the number of pictures in json during ajax request for instagram

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, instagram-api

I get just 20 pictures as a json respond for instagram. How can I change the limit

```
    $url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag_name}/media/recent?client_id={client_id}";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET", 
        dataType: 'jsonp', 
        url: $url,
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {         
            $.each(data['data'], function(index, element) { ...} 
   });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the maximum number of requests for Instagram?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322028/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-requests-for-instagram)

Answer (score 0):

Instagram API limit 20 images per request.

As you can see here [What is the maximum number of requests for Instagram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322028/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-requests-for-instagram][1])

Answer (score 0):

```
limit = 50;
//first time load animals
$img_type = 'animals';
url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/" + $img_type + "/media/recent?client_id={client_id}";
load_images();

function read_one_page(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET", 
        dataType: 'jsonp', 
        url: url,
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            var count = data.data.length;
            index = 0;
            while(index < count && img_number<limit)    {
                img_number++;
                element = data['data'][index];

                //create link to the large image
                var a = $('<a>').attr({href:element['images']['standard_resolution']['url']});

                //insert thumbnail img into the link
                a.append( $('<img>',{src:element['images']['thumbnail']['url'], alt:$img_type+" image"}) );


                //add new images to div
                $('#instafeed').append(a);
                index++;    
            }

            //add another two pages
            if ( data.pagination.next_url && img_number<limit ) {
                url = data.pagination.next_url;
                read_one_page();//call itself
            }   
        }//for success callback
    }); //for $.ajax                
}

function load_images(){
    img_number = 0;
    read_one_page();
}
```