# How many posts will Instagram's Tags/Recent Media Endpoint return?

Tags: instagram

We are using Instagram's Tags API, specifically the recent media endpoint. We ping every 10 minutes, and grab the newest posts since the last call. My question is how many posts will be returned? If we ping every 10 minutes, and 1,000s of posts happen with the hashtags relevant to us, will all of them be returned? Or will it max out at 20 or something and we have to keep paging through? Will it skip posts after a certain point? Unsure how this works.

Comment: A clear case of rtfm: https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322028/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-requests-for-instagram

Comment: @RobertMoskal that was not helpful in the least, I've read the documentation front to back. They don't specify a max value for count, and everything I've read says count is unreliable due to private posts being filtered AFTER the count is retrieved rather than prior, so the number returned is actually count minus number of private posts found in that total count.

Comment: @TomWoodward that was super helpful, thank you.