# User endpoint isn't showing the amount of count images

Tags: jquery, instagram

I'm working on a web application which can show you images from places, tags and users.

To get as many images from places at once, I use the `&count=100`. But this doesn't work for the tags and users.

I know that both tag and users have a pagination system (I already use this with the tags). But when you check the documentation for the users (http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/) it is saying that it also has a count.

Example: `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/3/media/recent/?access_token=4288348.f59def8.d8a1843ffd224e19af766fae3351efcb`

In my function I use the following code, which works, but only is displaying some random amount of images (between 1 and 7 or something).

```
var url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/" + name + "/media/recent/?access_token=" + access_token + "&count=10&callback=?";
```

Does anyone knows how I can get the most amount of images that is possible (I thought that was 100) at once?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying more than 20 photos in instagram API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311037/displaying-more-than-20-photos-in-instagram-api)

Comment: A bit. But still it is kind of odd that one user is displaying 3 photo's, while a other is displaying 11 photo's (for example)!